# Feature Importance for each class when p>>n

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics

I have a bioinformatics-related dataset with ~10k rows and ~100k columns (features) and a single response variable with roughly 25 classes. I want to figure out which of the features are useful in identifying each class. Any thoughts on how to proceed here?

Some initial thoughts I had here were to create 25 difference models (one for each class), where I could construct a binary response variable (one vs. all). But still unsure about how to deal with the p>>n case while maintaining interpretability. Would a logistic regression with a lasso penalty work? Or is there a cleaner solution (maybe hypothesis test / anova / etc.) that I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As section 3.3 of [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity/) notes, one solution is a multi-class logistic regression. That's generally preferable to sets of multiple one-versus-others or one-versus-one models. That text provides an example with a 10-class model and shows how to use a grouped LASSO if you want more overall sparsity in selected predictors. The combination of what predictors are selected and their associated regression coefficients then provides some measure of predictor importance.

An alternative is to use a tree-based multinomial model. The principles of tree-based models (bagged trees, random forest, boosted trees) are outlined in Chapter 8 of [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/). For implementation with boosted trees, both the [`gbm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gbm) and the [`xgboost` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xgboost) in R allow for multi-class analysis. The above tree-based models provide estimates of predictor importance based on measures, averaged over all the trees, of how much the predictor adds to performance when it's used in tree splits.

Be warned, however, that in the $p \gg n$ setting  all these approaches only provide estimates of "feature importance" for features that happened to be selected based on your particular dataset. The same type of model on a different dataset sampled from the underlying population might select a completely different set of features, as multiple predictors are inherently correlated in that setting. Thus the vagaries of sampling can lead to differences in what appear to be the "most important" features. You can evaluate this for yourself by repeating your modeling on multiple bootstrapped re-samples of your dataset.

Comment: thanks for your comments! Will these methods help understand which features are useful for each class? It seems like both suggested methods will help understand what features are important in the overall multi-class model

Comment: @m55667 I don't have much experience with the tree-based multi-class models, but I suspect that there is a way to get different importance for each class from them. The multi-class (penalized) logistic regression explained in Section 3.3 of SLS certainly provides different sets of predictors and associated coefficients for each class.